# How to run Saxon XSLT for all the files in the folder

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have list of files in the folder/subfolders. How to run a single XSLT to run all the files in the folder/subfolder. Is it possible in saxon command line?

I have tried the below command but its not working:

```
 java -jar saxon9.jar -o:foldername -xsl:xslfilename.xsl
```

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: See @MichaelKay's answer to a similar, albeit not quite duplicate, question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15020606/290085).

Comment: What do you mean by "list of files"? What version of Saxon? If the list is a file (XML preferably but plain text would work) with the paths and you're able to use the saxon extension functions, I can add an example that uses `saxon:discard-document` so you can process a lot of files without running out of memory.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using Saxon, you can use xslt 2.0 and the `collection` function.

for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat('file:///c:/filesarehere', '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))">
        <!--process nodes-->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: When I'm doing this I normally use `<xsl:template name="main">` as the entry point, and `-it:main` on the command line, to avoid the need for a dummy input document to match the `match="/"`. Also, I don't know if "c:/..." works as the collection URI, I would use "file:///c:/..."

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks - forgot about adding `file:///` - I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create one output file for each input file, with corresponding names, then you can set -s:inputDir and -o:outputDir on the command line, and it will process all the files in the directory. But this is a bit inflexible, for example if there are some non-XML files in the directory that you want to ignore. Controlling the process from within the stylesheet, using the collection() function, as suggested by @PhilVallone is more flexible.